# why cursor is not showing in tvOS Textfield

Tags: uitextfield, tvos

i am just adding a textfield and after clicking on textfield it opens new screen with keyboard. so there also cursor not showing.

Tried changing the tint color but its not affecting.

Comment: Include your attempt with question..

Comment: just added textfield and no extra code rather  tried changing tint color.